# Mocking in integration and end-to-end tests in airflow

Tags: python, mocking, airflow, pytest

I am new to Apache Airflow and am trying to perform integration and e2e tests on the complete DAG, not only operators, using some mock to fake the data sources.

After googling a lot I didn't find too much information so I would like to know if using pytest to test the whole DAG is really the correct way to follow here. If it is, how can I mock in this situation?

I tried something like this:

```
from unittest.mock import patch

@patch('package.module.myfunc'):
def test_if_dag_work(mock_data):
 
 mock_data.return_value = json_file
 dag.run(execution_date,next_execution_date)
 my asserts
```

But the mocking didn't work. I think that's because the airflow scope is different from the scope in which the function is executed.